# How to reconnect emulator after notification click?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, firebase-cloud-messaging, vscode-debugger

In my flutter & firebase app, I use cloud functions for notifications. My `onMessage`, `onResume` notifications works fine, but there's a problem on `onLaunch` notifications. After I terminate my app on an emulator, receive a notification, and click on the notification, the emulator shows a page, but never gets reconnected to my vscode IDE. It stays disconnected after `onLaunch` notification click. This is the screenshot when it's disconnected;[image]
However, I expect my emulator to be reconnected after `onLaunch` notification click in order to function properly. This is the screenshot when my emulator is connected to the vscode. [image]Why is this, and how can I reconnect my emulator to my vscode after `onLaunch` notification click? Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reconnect unless you run again the app, so if you can see what append in the onLaunch callback you can let the app in second plane without close because will be still connected and click on a notification

Comment: Hi Itamar. What do you mean by 'let the app in second plane'? How do you do that?